# Friction Not Working Between URDF and Database Model

Tags: friction

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am trying to model and control a conveyor using ROS/Gazebo, but right now it seems that objects I place on top of it just stay in place when I actuate it.

Here are screenshots showing the collision properties of the link from the URDF file and an example object:
[image: image description]
[image: image description]

I have attached the URDF file for the conveyor (ignore the .sdf extension added so that I could post it here).
[C:\fakepath\conveyor.urdf.xacro.sdf](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/15017775227384442.sdf)

Any ideas on how to debug this? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16928/friction-not-working-between-urdf-and-database-model/) by [rkeatin3](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/819/rkeatin3/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-08-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I suppose you have the problem when moving the conveyor with the controllers.
I made some tests to see what could be happening. My conclusion is that its highly probable that its something to do with the physiscs engine. Here you have a video that you can see the inconsistency in the way the objects interact with the standard ODE setting: [Video Answer](https://youtu.be/Y7ZPDzOTb7Q)

[image: conveyor belt working]

Because depending on when and how the frictions work or they don't. Normally if you move the belt slow enough it will work because it will give the system time to make the friction calculations.

My recommendation is that you try different configurations in the ODE parameters in the world.
Also try different friction parameters to make the friction bigger.
But As I sais it seems more of a ODE system issue than the friction coeficients values.

You could for example try using the "world" solver type instead of the "quick". Its more precise. Also increase the itterations and the update rate.

I post here as much code as I can:

[conveyor.urdf.xacro](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/15022039997306446.sdf)

[main.launch](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/1502204083306777.launch)

[friction_test_object.urdf](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/15022041346687971.sdf)

[conveyor.world](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/15022041499399592.world)

[spawn_friction_test_object.launch](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/15022041639743899.launch)

[spawn_conveyor.launch](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/1502204178410467.launch)

[conveyor.yaml](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/15022041927200283.sdf)

[conveyor_start_control.launch](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/1502204207353792.launch)

---

Originally posted by [Duckfrost](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2616/duckfrost/) with karma: 209 on 2017-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rkeatin3](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/819/rkeatin3/) on 2017-08-10**:
Thanks for this incredibly thorough answer!

It turns out that using the PositionJointInterface (as opposed to the EffortJointInterface) was the main problem I was facing; there was no friction at all using that interface. Maybe the lack of dynamics means that it wasn't exerting any force on the box?

I did see problems with the conveyor significantly slipping underneath the database model I had been using, but using a custom model with high friction values solves that problem.